# Connecting Raspberry Pi to iPhone HotSpot and using SSH

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, ssh

I am trying to connect my Raspberry Pi to my iPhone 5 with iOS 8 HotSpot. This works so far without problems, but when I try to connect to it with SSH, the connection always times out. I tried connecting to pi@raspberrypi, pi@raspberrypi.local and then went on trying to connect to a bunch of adresses in the DNS Range like 172.20.10.1-5 but without success. 
Does anyone of you know whether it is possible to establish a ssh connection this way?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You could try using the [Pi Finder](http://ivanx.com/raspberrypi/) utility to establish the Pi's IP address

Comment: Yeah, but this is only an opportunity, when I've got a Mac with me.